# How to repeat template with json data amount

Tags: angularjs

I want to repeat template with json data amount
there is no error show, it result just show incomplete html

here is my code

```
experiment.directive('groupsControl', function(){
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  transclude: false,
  template: '<div class="left"><div ng-repeat="group in children"><section-control sections="group"/></div></div>',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  }
}})

.directive('sectionControl', function(){
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  transclude: false,
  scope: { items:'=sections'},

  template: '<div ng-repeat="section in items" ng-include="getIncludeFile(section)">'+
            '</div>',

  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.getIncludeFile = function(section) {
        return '/Experiment_management_workspace/Experiment_management_project_angularJs/template/'+section + ".html";
    }


  }
}})
```

there is my template

```
<div><h3>Category1</h3>
<div ng-app="experiment">
  <ui>
    <li><a>{{data1.data1}}</a></li>
    <li><a>{{data1.data1}}</a></li>
  </ui>
```

json data

```
{"name": "test",
    "children":[
{"data": "function4" }, 
{"data": "function4" }, 
{"data": "function4" }]}
```

I hope it will be repeat three times, 
but result just show "Category1" three times,
I am so confused, please help

Comment: why don't you use a `templateURL` ?

Comment: where you have defined data1 i cant see in the code kindly set up a plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you presented works (at least, it does what you asked for, but with missing data). In order to display what you want correctly, I would suggest you some modifications :

First, I assume you defined the variable children somewhere  in your code, in order to get this working

```
<div ng-repeat="group in children">
```

Once this is done, the second directive is called correctly, then it load the ng-includes. But, in the template you provided there are many things that are not consistent. You use a variable called "data1", defined nowhere, it's totally normal that you only have 3 repeated "Category"s. You defined an isolate scope for your directive, so only the variables in attribute are available

I made an example, using inline templates, looking like that

```
<div><h3>Category1</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a>{{data1.data1}}</a></li>
        <li><a>{{data1.data2}}</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

and with almost no modification to your code, all is displayed. I modified mostly the link functions in both directives, in order to set the data that was missing :

Groups control :

```
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.children=[
                {"data": "function4" }, 
                {"data": "function5" }, 
                {"data": "function6" }]
  }
```

Section control :

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
scope.getIncludeFile = function(section) {
    return section + ".html";
}
scope.data1={data1:"Hello", data2:"World !"};
```

I've made a fiddle with this if you want to check http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/zhZXK/4/

I think your problem was just linked to missing data in the directive's scope